# <a> over <img> not working IE10

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11, internet-explorer-10

### HTML

```
<div class="cont" id="cont">
   <img class="c1" id="c1" src="..."></img>
</div>
<div class="men" id="men">
   <a href="..."></a>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.cont {
   float: left;
   display: inline-flex;
}

.c1 {
   position: absolute;
   right: 0;
}

.men {
   position: absolute;
   top: 10px;
   width: 385px;
   height: 50px;
   right: 80px;
}

.men > a {
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   width: 290px;
   height: inherit;
}
```

Bootstrap 3 is used.

### Problem

Using IE 11, everything is fine, the image is placed at the top right of the screen (theres also c2 and such to explain the flot left of .cont, but irrelevent for the problem) and the .men div is placed on top of the image at the desired location. However, in IE 10 it is placed behind the image. z-index also fails to do the job.

Comment: Could you use the [<map>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map) element instead?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than floating/positioning the link over the image, use the [`<map>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map) element...

```
<map name="imgmap">
   <area shape="rect" coords="385,10,465,60" href="..." alt="..." />
</map>
<img class="c1" id="c1" usemap="#imgmap" src="..." />
```

See the [`<area>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/area) tag for details of how to setup the `coords` correctly.

Answer (score 0):

As others ([freefaller](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37508211/3536236)) have stated, use an image map. **But**: while using an image map is a *better* approach, it still has significant disadvantages such as the map does not scale with the image (for example scaling to mobile device portrait/landscape orientation).

So instead use [SVG images](http://svgpocketguide.com/) with a built in, scalable, image mapping system. SVG images are - to sum up - images created using textual rules *very* similar to CSS stylesheets, and can have map clickable link elements incorporated into the SVG image.

a quick example, which will generate a square box of clickable link within an image. using CSS rules *on the HTML `<img>` element* this can then be scaled and the anchor on the SVG will scale in proporton:

**HTML (and SVG within)**

```
<figure id="burj">
    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 1200 808" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" >
    <image width="1200" height="808" xlink:href="burj-khalifa.jpg">
    </image>
    <a xlink:href="//burjkhalifa.ae/en/">
        <rect x="535" y="28" fill="#fff" opacity="0" width="150" height="750" />
        </a>
    </svg>
</figure>
```

**CSS**

```
figure {
    width:100%;
    max-width:808px;
}

figure svg {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
```

Very useful references for deeper exploration:

- http://www.creativebloq.com/netmag/create-responsive-svg-image-maps-51411831
- http://thenewcode.com/760/Create-A-Responsive-Imagemap-With-SVG

---

**P.s**
I have in the past used javascript/jQuery functions to "scale" standard `<map>` elements but have noticed that these are quite slow to respond, and seem to "clog" page load and refresh times somewhat, so appear (at a cursory glance) to be quite inefficient / processor heavy functions, I believe as they're constantly checking if and when the DOM is resizd for whatever reason.

Answer (score -2):

add `<!DOCTYPE html>` in you html page
try with img:hover {`enter code here`}

Comment: Doctype exists. The img:hover is irrelevent, as I'd like the link to be in a specific part of the image, not the whole.

Comment: for specific part of the image use map  as mention by @freefaller